# Video Editing - I toggled on and off stereoscopy and now my video preview is black

Tags: edit-mode, video-sequence-editor, video, stereoscopy

So toggling Stereoscopy on and then off made my preview go black, and it only reappears when I toggle Stereoscopy back on. I don't want Stereoscopy. How do I go back to normal?